# Which software should I use for making an YouTube intro for videos on a channel, and how long would I take to learn it?

Tags: premiere, after-effects, youtube

I was thinking you probably use Adobe Premiere and/or Adobe After Effects, but I'm not sure at all.

Also, how hard will it be? I have some basic experience with Photoshop and Illustrator if it matters.

Comment: This question is very opinion based. You could use a eg variety of tools here. Personally, I think for this purpose Premiere or AE are overkill, but others may disagree - it will depend on what you prefer.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to address your question.  What kind of intro do you envision?  Live action? Still images? 2D animated? 3D animated?  Without some knowledge of what you are trying to put together, it isn't possible to give a recommendation.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I should've given more information, I kind of forgot for some reason. Anyway, I was looking for something 2D or 3D animated, something like the intro for the videos on this channel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epLszn-rnpA

Comment: If you are updating your question, please do so by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you added in your comment, I would say you could use After Effects, and Premiere for this very easily...there may be easier/cheaper solutions but essentially what you are going for is pretty easy to make

Graphic designing aside you could probably learn and do this in a day or two, if you have any sort of background in photoshop or computers.

Start here, I am pretty sure this is where I learned how to use After Effects http://www.videocopilot.net/basic/